# PHP Cookies using Variable from URL

Tags: php, url, cookies, parameter-passing

I'm no PHP expert and I'm trying to set a cookie that contains a referrer code from the URL. For example: `www.example.com?promotioncode=google` should set a cookie name promocode, value what ever is after the `=` and a 6 month expiry.

I can retrieve the promotioncode using

```
$_GET['promotioncode']
```

but I can't seem to insert this into the cookie string. I've tried a few ways:

```
$id = 'promo';
$value = $_GET['promotioncode'];
$time = time()+60*60*24*180;
setcookie($id, $value, $time);
```

and

```
$id = 'promo';
$time = time()+60*60*24*180;
setcookie($id, $_GET['promotioncode'], $time);
```

but it doesn't work. If I use a word or number as the cookie value then the cookie is set no problem.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the HTTP response header? Your attempt to set a cookie might fail due to the fact that the header has already been send. Did you check your error log?

Comment: This is actually on a magento installation and this is being added in the same way as other cookies generated by magento.. if I set the value to 123 it works fine, the problem is pulling through the parameter from the url.

Comment: That code should work, and it does works here. 

How do you know it doesn't work? Do you check the cookies or do you check the return value from setcookie()? Did you vardump the content of $_GET? Anything strange about that?

Answer (score 3):

Add a parameter to define the path on the server in which the cookie will be available on :

```
setcookie($id, $value, $time, '/');
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are no differences between a simple `$string` and `$_GET['key']`, so the problem can't be this.

Also check your 4th arg of `setcookie`

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
if($_GET['promotioncode'])
    setcookie(.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

$id = $_GET['promotioncode'];
setcookie('promotioncode', $id, time()+60*30*24*3600 , '/' );

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setcookie($id, "" . $value, $time);
```

The blank string ("") may help clarify or set the type of $value. The quotes basically make sure that the $value variable is passed in as a string parameter to the setcookie method.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.